# How to fix "DocuSign Payments is currently unavailable. Try again later."

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm trying to add payment fields to my envelope on my sandbox account. 
For the start I tried to use the example code which DocuSign provides on [Github](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core).
But when I'm using the code I get the following error: 
"DocuSign Payments is currently unavailable. Try again later."

What do I need to fix the issue?
Is the payments feature not working on the DocuSign sandbox?

I have set up the Payment Gateway with Paypal.
The user I use to do the request is DocuSign Admin. 
I've tried also to use the latest DocuSign SDK code version 4.0.0rc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means that the Payment feature is not enabled on your DocuSign environment. 
To get it enabled you have to contact DocuSign support.

After they have enabled the Payment feature on my sandbox I was able to use the example code.